# How to add virtual environment to VSCode Launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

As the title suggests, I'm using the VSCode debugger to launch a django app.  I created the virtual env using  `python3 -m virtualenv venv` and it's shown below in the place I'd like to have it.  I've checked the VSCode django and debugging tutorials but am no closer to an answer than I was when I started.

```
vscode ➜ /workspaces/docker-test-proj $ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 8 vscode vscode 256 Apr  6 14:30 helloworld


vscode ➜ /workspaces/docker-test-proj/helloworld $ ls -l
total 136
drwxr-xr-x 11 vscode vscode    352 Apr  6 13:24 app
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode 131072 Apr  6 13:42 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x  8 vscode vscode    256 Apr  6 13:21 helloworld
-rwxr-xr-x  1 vscode vscode    666 Apr  6 13:19 manage.py
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode    175 Apr  6 14:30 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x  6 vscode vscode    192 Apr  6 13:20 venv
```

Where do I need to put the `source venv/bin/activate` command in my launch.json file  below to have it run when starting the VSCode debugger?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
            ],
            "django": true
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You do not need to add `activate` to `launch.json`. You have 3 options (I prefer the first option):

1. Provide the complete path to `python` in the virtual environment. Here is one of my launch configurations. The `python` entry points to the `python` executable image in a virtual environment.

   ```json
       {
         "justMyCode": false,
         "name": "Ancient Warmth / Django-Oscar",
         "type": "python",
         "request": "launch",
         "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
         "python": "${env:oscar}/bin/python",
         "args": [
           "runserver",
           "--noreload",
           "0.0.0.0:8001",
         ],
         "django": true
       },
   ```

   Note that the above refers to an environment variable called `oscar` that points to the virtual environment. I define `oscar` in `.bashrc` like this:

   ```
   export oscar=/var/work/django/oscar
   ```

   It does not matter where the environment variable is defined, so long as it is defined before VSCode runs.
2. At the bottom of the VSCode window, near the left side, you will find the name of the Python environment being used.

   a. Click on it and a list of the workspaces drops down from the top.

   b. Select the workspace that you want to modify the Python for, then you will see a list of Python interpreters. The one you want is probably not shown, so click on "I can't find the interpreter I want to select...", then click "Find...".

   c. Navigate to your virtual environment and click on `python`.
3. This option is a manual way of producing the same change as option #2. Edit the file called `.vscode/settings.json` in your project directory and set `python.pythonPath` to point to the `python` program in your virtual environment. Here is my complete `.vscode/settings.json` file:

   ```json
   {
     "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
     "python.linting.enabled": true,
     "python.pythonPath": "/var/work/django/oscar/bin/python"
   }
   ```

Comment: The third answer does not work when at the bottom left the python interpreter does not have a `(venv)` beforehand I think but refers to the system python.

Comment: That is not my experience, all that is required is that the `python` interpreter is present at the specified location and that it runs.

Comment: That has worked for me. However, the execution can't find a `credentials.json` file in the same directory as the Python execution file.

Comment: Method 1 is not working for me in latest version of vscode.  I've added `export oscar=/my/virtualenv/path` to my `~/.zshrc` and it didn't work

Answer (score 7):

I gave @mike-slinn a +1 because it pointed me in the right direction but if you are a windows user of venv, this is exactly what I did. Open the launch.json and add the following:

```
 "python":"C:/Users/[pathto]/[projectfolder]/.venv/Scripts/python.exe"
```

**Full File:**

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "python": "C:/Users/cullen/pathto/projectfolder/.venv/Scripts/python.exe",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is adding to launch.json this one line:

```
"python": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/bin/python",
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're like me and you followed this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) you'll want to setup your `launch.json` file with the `pythonPath`.

I placed my `bin` directly in the root of my working directory

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            ...
            "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/python",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```