# No module named uvicorn when debugging through vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm using Remote-Containers to debug an FastApi app. The container has all the dependecies installed. When I try to debug using the vscode debugger I got the error `No module named uvicorn`. But if I run `uvicorn api.main:app` it works.

/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3 /Users/juracylopes/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 59746 -- -m uvicorn api.main:app
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: **No module named uvicorn**

My launch.json:

````
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: FastAPI",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "uvicorn",
            "args": [
                "api.main:app"
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
} ```
````

Comment: If uvicorn is not installed as a module, the command line application should not be installed as well. So if you have the latter, the former IS installed in the same environment. The error you're getting is from a different Python than the one you can successfully run uvicorn, and therefore, the whole environment is different.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've installed uvicorn in a virtual environment in your workspace?  In that case, the Python that VSCode is running for your debugging session might not be referencing your venv.

I'm using `python -m venv .venv` to create my virtual environment, so my venv Python is at `${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python`.

Consider adding this to your project .vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python"
}
```

And then reloading your session to enable remote debugging via a `module` with your session referencing the virtual environment.

Reference:

[How to add virtual environment to VSCode launch JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66971452/how-to-add-virtual-environment-to-vscode-launch-json)